# Refactoring common code in switch code

Tags: java

```
switch (customerPaymentInfo.getPtType()) {
        case CASH:
            test();
            otherMethod1();
            break;
        case CARD:
            test();
            otherMethod2();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Payment Type is Not Correct.");
    }
```

In the above code I am having one common method which one executing for both case CASH or CARD.

Is there any possibilities in switch case to use it single times?

For eaxmple in case of If block we can write code something below :

```
if (customerPaymentInfo.getPtType().equals("CASH") || customerPaymentInfo.getPtType().equals("CARD")) {
    test();
}
```

Comment: You can write multiple cases as `case CASH: case CARD: do stuff; break;` if that's what you mean. That doesn't exactly fit your use case though.

Comment: Can you call `test` before the `switch`?

Comment: If you are planning to add functionalities this may grow wildly and another problem will occur. Better approach would be to use some strategy pattern to handle diffrent cases...

Comment: No. Because I only common for cash or card. I also have other cases

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would be good to look at this from another angle. Why is there a switch at all? It looks like `otherMethod1()` and `otherMethod2()` are doing the same thing in different ways, dependeing on the payment type.

I image `othMethod1()` could be something like `processPaymentByCash()` and `processPaymentByCard()`. Then the differences in implementation should rather be handled by the different classes for those payment types:

```
class PaymentCash extends Payment {
    processPayment() {
        test();
        // Code from othermethod1
    }
}

class PaymentCard extends Payment {
    processPayment() {
        test();
        // Code from othermethod2
    }
}

class PaymentWhatever extends Payment {
    processPayment() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Payment Type is Not Correct.");
    }
}
```

Above switch would then simply be replaced by this one liner:

```
customerPaymentInfo.getPtType().processPayment();
```

Now, you still have two calls to `test()` in your code, but IMHO this really all depends on the bigger context of your code.

It also looks like the different payment types should rather be implemented as enum values.

Comment: It a great idea to replace switch case by class. But I need some more clarification. What payment class consist?

Comment: Can you please put some more details

Comment: This is a [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). It is called [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Another example I just found is [here](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

Comment: Yes.  It's clear now.  How I called. ? You mentioned single statement for calling those  methods

Comment: customerPaymentInfo.getPtType() its a enum. How do I called payment class using this enum?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to use the cascading property of `switch`

```
switch (customerPaymentInfo.getPtType()) {
    case CASH:
    case CARD:
        test();
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Payment Type is Not Correct.");
}

switch (customerPaymentInfo.getPtType()) {
    case CASH:
        otherMethod1();
        break;
    case CARD:
        otherMethod2();
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Payment Type is Not Correct.");
}
```

Now however you have redundancy on `switch` statements.

Another way would be to first check of the `IllegalArgumentException`, then run `test()` then do a switch statement:

```
if (!customerPaymentInfo.getPtType().equals(CASH) || !customerPaymentInfo.getPtType().equals(CARD))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Payment Type is Not Correct.");
test();
switch(customerPaymentInfo.getPtType()) {
  //switch code
}
```

Finally, a Java8 only soltion, if you have many such cases (where they have a common call and a specific call) you might group them for the common call and for the specific part you could use a map of Enums and Functions.

```
switch (customerPaymentInfo.getPtType()) {
    case CASH:
    case CARD:
        test();
        functionMap.get(customerPaymentInfo.getPtType()).apply(holderOfOtherMethod);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Payment Type is Not Correct.");
}
```